# There is a lot of noise in the images I add to the video sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor

There is a lot of noise in the images(jpeg file) I add to the video sequencer.
Is there a way to remove the noise?[image][image: Rendered_1920x1080.jpg]

Comment: maybe it is just in the preview...did you try to render?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to render.
The original resolution is 3456x5184 and there was no noise when exporting at that size. However, there was noise when exporting at 1920x1080(I scaled down the image to fit the screen.). I would like to use it in a 1920x1080 slideshow.

Comment: I have no idea why there is noise when you resize to a lower resolution but you may try to resize it in another program and the add it back to Blender?

Comment: can u provide an example blend file, maybe just with one image where this happens?

Comment: I have uploaded the original image and blend file where this happens.
https://52.gigafile.nu/0329-d455c0d65fbec33612fb040d52555be78

Comment: @mqbaka mqbaka.
I resized it with Affinity photo and then added it back to Blender.
Then there was no noise.
Thank you for your advice!
If possible, it would be easier if the noise could be eliminated with Blender, so if anyone has other setting methods that can be done with Blender, I would be grateful if you could continue to give me advice.

Comment: This beats me. I really have no idea why it's like this. I'm guessing it's the way Blender interpolates the images with that causes that but I don't have any idea on how to check that out. I managed to find a way to have a noiseless render in 2.79 but I can't reproduce it in 3.0 or 2.9.

Comment: @mqbaka mqbaka. I see. thank you. I'm looking forward to the Blender update!